# sdcard drive not detected so sdcards not showing up in Ubuntu 16.04 unlike 14.04

Tags: sd-card

I have this problem with an Intel Compute Stick, the sdcard drive was detected in Ubuntu 14.04 but after upgrading to 16.04, sdcards are not detected & no longer show up anywhere using any command as 
ls /dev/ | grep sd - 
or lsusb, 
or in gparted. 
maybe the module handling it got borked.
As I rely on special modded distros from Linuxium, I have to wait for an upgrade from him I guess...

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.1 and 14.04.5 LTS are supported until April 2019, so for two more years. Is it possible for you to continue using this version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by patching the 4.11 RC8,7 & 5 kernels and compiling them for the Hannspree HDMI Intel Baytrail stick.
For those interested who happen to have the irq8 conflict problem, I uploaded my one patched Kernel 4.11-RC8 deb files (image & header)
It's a zip file - passw: 2020
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbc04c2u46vxgye/Linux-4.11-RC8.zip?dl=0
the patch comes from here:
https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/6137291/

Comment: It will nice if Ubuntu solves this sdcard reader not recognised problem in future versions.